# How do I prove that quadratic optimization matrix has all eigenvalues smaller than 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

The goal is to optimize a quadratic function of the form:
$$
H(x) = \frac{1}{2} x \left( \begin{array}{cc} Q_{11} & Q_{12} \\ Q_{21} & Q_{22} \end{array}\right) x + x^T b
$$
where Q is positive definite symmetric. This leads to the stability requirement that matrix G:
$$
G = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & -Q_{11}^{-1} Q_{12} \\ - Q_{22}^{-1} Q_{21} & 0 \end{array} \right)
$$
must have all eigenvalues smaller than 1:
$$ 
|\text{eig}(G)| < 1 
$$
for the system to be stable.  My question is how can I prove for the given Q that G does indeed fulfill this property?

Comment: Are these block matrices or just numbers?

Comment: These are block matrices. Q as a whole is positive definite symmetric, so Q11 and Q22 are too.

Comment: And when you say $Q$ do you mean each block or the whole matrix?

Comment: The whole matrix, not all individual blocks.

Comment: So then $Q_{12}$ is just the transpose of $Q_{21}$? (Just trying to sort out notation, sorry for the hassle.)

Comment: Yes that is correct.